Troubleshooting Docker Errors Encountered During Terminal Execution
I created a web api with dotnet cli similar to:
dotnet new wepapi -o Auth -n Auth

so my project structure looks like this:
Auth/
├── Auth.sln
├── Auth/
  ├── Controllers/
  │   └──AuthController.cs
  ├── Program.cs
  ├── Dockerfile
  ├── ... (other project files)
├── .gitignore

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AuthFirebase/AuthFirebase.csproj", "AuthFirebase/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./AuthFirebase/AuthFirebase.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AuthFirebase"
RUN dotnet build "./AuthFirebase.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./AuthFirebase.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AuthFirebase.dll"]

When I run it in Visual Studio 2022 it work perfectly.
But When I Try to run it in my terminal, a get these errors:

From root path AuthFirebase

docker build -f "C:\XXX\YYY\back\AuthFirebase\AuthFirebase\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t authfirebase:dev

ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker buildx build --help'.

Usage:  docker buildx build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -


Inside AuthFirebase/AuthFirebase

docker build -t auth-firebase:dev .
2024/06/03 16:51:12 http2: server: error reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed
[+] Building 1.0s (9/17)                                                                                 docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 922B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0                                                  0.6s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0@sha256:1e0c55b0ae732f333818f13c284a01c0e3a2ec431491e23c0a52  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.3s
 => => transferring context: 12.19MB                                                                               0.3s
 => [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [build 3/7] COPY [AuthFirebase/AuthFirebase.csproj, AuthFirebase/]                                       0.0s
------
 > [build 3/7] COPY [AuthFirebase/AuthFirebase.csproj, AuthFirebase/]:
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
  11 |     WORKDIR /src
  12 | >>> COPY ["AuthFirebase/AuthFirebase.csproj", "AuthFirebase/"]
  13 |     RUN dotnet restore "./AuthFirebase/AuthFirebase.csproj"
  14 |     COPY . .
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 7cba1a75-4104-405a-b131-1042fe9d887e::0t3gma9izi8oxgfv5hlm8nuct: "/AuthFirebase/AuthFirebase.csproj": not found

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/default/default/i5vc29i0p6l5x4awjwwm11mg8

